# Html Menu button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i want to click menu button and close or change Welcome Jon deo  inside div `class="greetings"` to G

like if the menu button clicked. show G and remove or hide Welcome Jon deo

also when the page is browsed or visited on tablet show G automatically

```
<html>
  <header>
    <title>This is title</title></header>
  <body>
  <button type="button">menu</button>
  <div class="greetings">
  <br>
    <span>Welcome Jon deo</p>
  </div>
    <div class="this">
      <br>
    </div>
    <span>Web Content</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide 'Welcome Jon deo', you will need to simply change the `<span>` to `<p>` and add an `id` attribute to it so you can select it in your css code, also add another `<p>` element and give it an `id` and hide it with css and javascript. You will also need to add an `id` to your button so you can select it with javascript. I labeled the changes made to your HTML code.

```
<html>
  <header>
    <title>This is title</title>

    ****CHANGE HERE***
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  </header>
  <body>
  <button id="menuBtn" type="button">menu</button> ***CHANGE HERE***
  <div class="greetings">
  <br>
    <p id="text">Welcome Jon deo</p> ***CHANGE HERE***
    <p id="text2">G</p> ***CHANGE HERE***
  </div>
    <div class="this">
      <br>
    </div>
    <span>Web Content</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE to hide 'G' unless on tablets or phones

```
#text2 {
  display: none;
}
```

You will need to add this javascript to your code to change 'Welcome etc etc' to 'G'

```
const text = document.getElementById('text');
const menuBtn = document.getElementById('menuBtn');

// Add click event to menu button
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', changeText);

// Function to change text
function changeText() {
    text.innerHTML = 'G';
};
```

In order to automatically display 'G' on smaller screens you will need to add the meta tags to your HTML code (see above changes in your code) and add media queries to your css.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        #text {
           display: none;
        }
        #text2 {
           display: block;
        }
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        #text {
           display: none;
        }
        #text2 {
           display: block;
        }
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
       #text {
           display: none;
        }
        #text2 {
           display: block;
        }
}
```

Comment: i tried it and not working, even the welcome jon deo is hidden by default here the link of the full code after putting it together [link] (https://output.jsbin.com/dilidiluqi) **bold**

Comment: May I see the full code? HTML, CSS, JavaScript so I can see how it is all put together?

Comment: You just copied and pasted the code, of course it won't work. Remove the comments, and remove the type="text/css" from the style tag. Add the javascript code to your html code.